# Database structure to avoid duplicate entries

Tags: database

I have three tables: Parent_table,Child_table and child_of_child_table.

I have three senarios.

1. If some one change in parent table then there is clone of every table in database.
2. if some one change in child_of_child_table then there is clone of every table in database.
3. if some one change in parent and child_of_child table then there is clone of every table in database.

For example:
If someone changes the name of ABC to DEF in parent table. Then it will create new version of data in parent_table, child_table and child_of_child _table.

I do not want this duplicate entry in database. Can any one help me to create database structure?

Comment: We can't see images that are on your machine, upload them using the image upload button. Anyway, why do you have different tables for the same entity types? Indicating whether someone has a parent can be done using a ParentId column, not through separate tables. Learn about normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Why use mutliple tables? You only need one. 
ID, Parent_ID, Name

This can be how ever deep you need it to be.

The question is how do you want to consume it?

This is how I usually do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[group_hierarchy]( @pGroupID AS INTEGER)
RETURNS @Groups TABLE( ItemID      INTEGER NOT NULL
                      ,NestedLevel INTEGER NOT NULL )
AS BEGIN

DECLARE
  @lNestedLevel INTEGER;

  SET @lNestedLevel = 0;

  IF( @pGroupID IS NULL ) RETURN;
  ELSE
  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Groups
      SELECT @pGroupID, 1
    WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT NULL
      FROM  Group
      WHERE Group_ID = @pGroupID );
  END;-->IF<--

  WHILE( @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 )
  BEGIN

    SET @lNestedLevel = @lNestedLevel + 1;

    INSERT INTO @Groups
    SELECT Group_ID, ( @lNestedLevel + 1)
    FROM   Group
    WHERE  ParentGroup_ID IN (
           SELECT ItemID
           FROM @Groups
           WHERE NestedLevel = @lNestedLevel );
  END;-->WHILE<--

  RETURN;

END
```